# Php (Laravel) Locale issue

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, locale

I need to localize the dates in `Laravel (Php)`. I'am using `Carbon` for manipulating dates.

*Here are some examples and outputs.*

**EX: 1** *(Working correctly)*

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'id');
dd(Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y'));
```

[image]

---

**EX: 2** *(Not working)*

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'zh-TW');
dd(Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y'));
```

[image]

Here the `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'zh-TW');` not working correctly as you can see in the output. it should out put something like `星期二`.

What is the problem in here? and How to overcome this? Thank you.

**Note:** I'am using `XAMP` in `Windows-8.1`.

Comment: I am not sure but try to write "zh-TW.utf8" and "zh_TW.UTF-8 UTF-8"

Comment: no both are falling back to english

Answer (score 0):

Try to set locale with this

```
Carbon::setLocale('de');
```

Comment: Sorry this is only for `Carbon` `diffForHumans()` locale, Not for localizing all the Carbon date stuffs.